# Is it possible to force pandas not to convert data type when using DataFrame.replace

Tags: python, pandas

Here's a working example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [-39882300000000000000]}, dtype='object')
```

`df.replace({',': '.'})`  raises an `OverflowError` because somewhere in the code the `convert` flag is set to True. I am not sure but it is probably because pandas is inferring that it only contain numbers.

I read the data from an Excel workbook and I want to prevent this conversion when using `df.replace`. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: IIUC convert it to `str`.  `df.astype(str).replace({',': '.'})`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
df.update(df.blocks['object'].astype(str).replace({',': '.'}))
```

Comment: You remember I brought it up a while ago... this is the first time I've used it to answer a question (-:

Comment: @MaxU It is. And it doesn't have any underscores so can we assume it is part of the public API?

Comment: @ayhan, there is a documented method: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.as_blocks.html

Comment: @ayhan neither does `get_value` or `set_value` but jeff told me that it wasn't intended as public api.  So, still not sure

Comment: yeah this should be deprecated as well

Comment: @Jeff what specifically?  blocks, as_blocks, or get/set_value?

Comment: alll of those are slated for deprecation ; they just bloat the API

Answer (score 7):

How about this:

```
In [25]: df.loc[:, df.dtypes=='object'] = \
             df.select_dtypes(['object']).astype(str).replace({',': '.'})
```

This will apply `.replace` only to columns of a `string` (`object`) dtype